# Override a column property from abstract class in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy (2.0) I have an abstract class that inherits from the Declarative Base:

```
class ManagedEntity(Base):
    __abstract__ = True
    __id : Mapped[int] = mapped_column("id", primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    @declared_attr.directive
    def __tablename__(cls) -> str:
        name : str = cls.__name__[0].lower()
        for char in cls.__name__[1:]:
            if (char.isupper()):
                name += "_"
            name += char.lower()

        return name

    @property
    def id(self) -> int:
        return self.__id
```

Then any other class that gets stored in the db inherits from that class. However is it possible to override the __id field so that for some classes its not autoincremented.

Simply redeclaring the __id attribute results in a duplicate column error.